# Do iMessage or text messages show sent or received time after your iPhone is off?

Tags: iphone, messages

If your iPhone is off, do text messages continue to show real times that they were sent to you OR the time when you turned the phone back on?

Answer (score 1):

The time stamp shows the time the message was *successfully* sent. This is shown in local time (i.e. whatever time it was in your time zone).